# Trigger to update Materialised view after an insert on another materialised view Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I am trying to trigger a refresh for a materialised view after an Insert,update or delete on another materialised view. I am trying to use a triggered function to achieve this. Script is as follows;

```
CREATE FUNCTION aza_ods_version1.populate_fact_churn_m() 
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW aza_ods_version1.fact_churn_monthly;
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER refresh_fact_churn_monthly
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE OR TRUNCATE
  ON aza_ods_version1.fact_transactions
  FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (OLD.* IS DISTINCT FROM NEW.*)
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE aza_ods_version1.populate_fact_churn_m();
```

On attempting to create the trigger, I get this error; 
ERROR:  "fact_transactions" is not a table or view
SQL state: 42809

I think its because fact_transactions is a materialized view and not a view or table. 
Is there a way i can achieve what i am trying to??

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
[The documentation for CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtrigger.html)  doesn't mention materialized views:

```
table_name The name (optionally schema-qualified) of the table, view, or foreign table the trigger is for.
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put a trigger on a materialized view, you will need to put the trigger on each table references in the query that generated the materialized. Further for [TRUNCATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtrigger.html) you will need to create a separate trigger:

> In addition, triggers may be defined to fire for TRUNCATE, though only
> FOR EACH STATEMENT.